# Installing Drupal 8.x using composer BUT using a local mirror

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I'm installing Drupal 8.x via composer downloading any dependencies from the Internet and all works fine.

In this way however there is no guarantee that the same versions of dependencies will be available every time I install. One server might have an updated version of a module than another Drupal server if I install in different time. I would like to prevent against this by using a local mirror.

Is it possible to provide a local mirror to composer and how?

Any example / reference / suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about the versions, then the best way would be to define the exact versions you want in your `composer.json` if need. But apart from that, after you install your dependencies, you have a `composer.lock` file that has the exact versions in it. This file is committed to your version control and used as the base to install: this way you always get the same versions (until you update of course).

A separate problem might be that there is no internet, or the specific versions are not available for some reason. This shouldn't happen (often), but in that case you should pick this up before you 'release'. 
The best practice would be to build (finding out if you have all packages available) and then release. You could even create a separate build server that creates your project including the vendor dir, and push from there. The fact that your vendor dir is not in your version control does not mean you have to get all dependencies on your production server each time
This means you have a local copy of your vendor, which is not a local mirror of composer per se, but close enough for comfort.